# Industrial machinery and equipment

Tags: mechanical-engineering, manufacturing-engineering, process-engineering, petroleum-engineering

I am a mechanical engineer who is interested in learning different processes and equipment mainly used in process industry namely, textile, chemical, sugar mill, and other food process industry.
Is there a one place to go solution available or if someone can help me and guide me to resources available online that can help me in understanding how these industries work in term of processes and equipment.

Comment: This looks like a [resource-hunting question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/10/1832). Such questions are prone to becoming out-dated, and are therefore considered off-topic for this site.

Comment: The trick seems to be recognising what exists elsewhere and seeing how it can be applied in your field to improve what exists ... good luck.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because resource hunting is offtopic, although the question would by otherways ontopic. You may get answers on the chat or in comments.